# HttpRequest: inconsistent Scheme & Host properties

Tags: http, asp.net-core, kubernetes-ingress

My ASP.NET Core 3.1 application runs in Kubernetes. The ingress (load balancer) terminates SSL and talks to the pod over plain HTTP.

Let's say the ingress is reachable at https://my-app.com:443, and talks to the pod (where my app is running) at http://10.0.0.1:80.

When handling a request, the middleware pipeline sees an [`HttpRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-3.1) object with the following:

- `Scheme == "http"`
- `Host.Value == "my-app.com"`
- `IsHttps == False`

This is weird:

- Judging by the `Scheme` (and `IsHttps`), it seems the `HttpRequest` object describes the forwarded request from the ingress to the pod, the one that goes over plain HTTP. However, why isn't `Host.Value` equal to `10.0.0.1` in that case?
- Or vice versa: if `HttpRequest` is trying to be clever and represent the original request, the one to the ingress, why doesn't it show `"https"` along with `"my-app.com"`?

At no point in handling the request is there a request coming to http://my-app.com. It's either https://my-app.com or http://10.0.0.1. The combination is inconsistent.

#### Other details

Digging deeper, the `HttpRequest` object has the following headers (among others) that show the reverse proxying in action:

```
Host: my-app.com
Referer: https://my-app.com/swagger/index.html
X-Real-IP: 10.0.0.1
X-Forwarded-For: 10.0.0.1
X-Forwarded-Host: my-app.com
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Scheme: https
```

I'm guessing `HttpRequest` is using these to get hold of the original host (my-app.com rather than 10.0.0.1) but it doesn't do the same for the original scheme (https rather than http).

**Q1**: Is this expected, and if so, what is the rationale?

**Q2**: What's the best way to get at the original URL (https://my-app.com)? The best I've found so far was to check if the `X-Scheme` and `X-Forwarded-Host` headers were present (by inspecting `HttpRequest.Headers`) and if so, using those. However, it's a little weird having to go to the raw HTTP headers in the middleware pipeline.

Comment: Are you aware of UseForwardedHeaders?  ASP.NET Core has built-in support, but it is locked down to only localhost/127.0.0.1 by default, so when running in k8s behind ingress you have to turn on ForwardedHeaders then clear the "KnownNetworks" redstriction.  It is unfortunate this is so hard to find how to do correctly, since HTTPS termination is so common in non-trivial hosting scenarios.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0#forward-the-scheme-for-linux-and-non-iis-reverse-proxies

Comment: Thanks, that seems very relevant. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: Is this expected, and if so, what is the rationale?

I would say yes, it's the expected behavior.

The `'Host.Value=my-app.com'` of `HttpRequest` object is reflecting the request header field originated by client (web browser, curl, ...), e.g.:

```
curl --insecure -H 'Host: my-app.com' https://<FRONTEND_FOR_INGRESS-MOST_OFTEN_LB-IP>
```

which is set*[1] in location block for that server `'my-app.com'` inside generated `nginx.conf` file:

```
                    ...
                    set $best_http_host                     $http_host;
                    # [1] - Set Host value 
                    proxy_set_header Host                   $best_http_host;
                    ...
                    # Pass the extracted client certificate to the backend
                    ...
                    proxy_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;             
                    proxy_set_header X-Request-ID           $req_id;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $best_http_host;
                    ...
```

whereas '[http_host](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_)' variable is created based on following `"ngx_http_core_module"` core functionality:

> $http_name - 
>   arbitrary request header field; the last part of a variable name is the field name converted to lower case with dashes replaced by underscores

So described behavior is not anyhow unique to ASP.NET Core 3.0, you see unknown Dictionary containing key/value pairs of custom headers set explicitly by nginx controller, accordingly to nginx ingress current configuration, that's it.

You can inspect current nginx controller's configuration by your self with following command:

```
kubectl exec -it po/<nginx-ingress-controller-pod-name> -n <ingress-controller-namespace> -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

> Q2: What's the best way to get at the original URL
>   (https://my-app.com)?

I would try with constructing it using [Configuration](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) snippet, this is by introducing another custom header, where you concatenate values.

Comment: Thanks, @Nepomucen. I can confirm this is the case, my `nginx.conf` contains much the same directives like you've shown. So, to summarise, .NET Core sets
(1) `HttpRequest.Scheme` to the actual scheme of the ELB-to-pod request (`"http"` if the ELB terminates SSL) but (2) `HttpRequest.Host.Value` to the value of the `"Host"` header in this ELB-to-pod request (which the reverse proxy at the ELB sets as per the `nginx.conf`'s `proxy_set_header Host`), rather than the pod's IP. Sorry it took me so long to respond, I've spent all that time trying to get access to my `nginx.conf`.